# Systemd user service with root permissions

Tags: permissions, systemd, sudo, users

I want to create a systemd service that will `reboot --force` my system whenever GPU falls off the bus. I wrote a dedicated script for that purpose (`/home/heinwol/.local/bin/reboot_after_gpu_breaks.sh`). However, I don't quite understand how users and permissions work in Linux, hence my solution doesn't work.

First of all, I appended the following line to the sudoers file:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/heinwol/.local/bin/reboot_after_gpu_breaks.sh
```

Ownership and permissions of this script are shown below:

```
$ ls -l reboot_after_gpu_breaks.sh

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 384 окт 10 14:57 reboot_after_gpu_breaks.sh
```

And it works in the sense that I can simply run it as a regular user without sudo. However, I cannot make it to work with systemd.

More precisely, I have the following **user** service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Reboot the system when gpu falls off the bus

[Service]
Type=simple
User=heinwol
Group=heinwol
StandardOutput=journal
ExecStart="/home/heinwol/.local/bin/reboot_after_gpu_breaks.sh"
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I enable this service, it shouts:

```
окт 10 15:28:02 heinwol-lenovo systemd[1322]: Started Reboot the system when gpu falls off the bus.
окт 10 15:28:02 heinwol-lenovo systemd[3287]: reboot_after_gpu_breaks.service: Failed to determine supplementary groups: Operation not permitted
окт 10 15:28:02 heinwol-lenovo systemd[3287]: reboot_after_gpu_breaks.service: Failed at step GROUP spawning /home/heinwol/.local/bin/reboot_after_gpu_breaks.sh: Operation not permitted
окт 10 15:28:02 heinwol-lenovo systemd[1322]: reboot_after_gpu_breaks.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP
окт 10 15:28:02 heinwol-lenovo systemd[1322]: reboot_after_gpu_breaks.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What is actually happening is a security feature from systemd to prevent you from using setuid in services.
If you add NoNewPrivileges=false to your service file it should work properly.

However, I cannot recommend you to use setuid as it is a major security flaw.

Could you not put your service under root ?

It help avoid security flaw and even if you need to run some things in your script as a user, it is better to just switch user in a service run as root for these task rather than using the setuid.
You can even remove your sudo rule in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Though I didn't manage it to work with just putting `NoNewPrivileges=false` into my service file, it seems like it's a bit more complex task. Anyways, I decided to make a system service which, of course, works. The problem now is that I want this service to be active only when my user's session is active

Comment: There are no easy way to do that. You could try to check in your script if your user is running and if not put a sleep in there to reduce load.( Though load would be irelevant)